# Flask app placing elements on body that are placed on template's head

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the following simple flask app with a template:

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',\
        title = "My Title"
    )
```

`layout.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body class="mx-3">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body"> 
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="static/js/jquery-3.7.0.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        {% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

`index.html`

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
{{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<p class="display-4">Hello from index</p>

{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
<script src="static/js/scripts.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

When I run this app with `flask --app app run` the following HTML is generated. Notice how the head elements are placed on top of the body element and the strange `&#xFEFF;` (Zero Width No-Break Space) text.

Generated HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body class="mx-3">﻿
        "&#xFEFF; "
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title> My Title </title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">   

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body"> 
                <p class="display-4">Hello from index</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="static/js/jquery-3.7.0.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What may be causing this? This is really the minimal reproducible example that I could produce.

I only installed flask with `pip install flask` on a virtual environment.

Python version: 3.11.4

Flask version: 2.3.2

My folder structure looks like this:

```
├───static
│   ├───css
│   │       bootstrap.min.css
│   │       style.css
│   │
│   └───js
│           bootstrap.bundle.min.js
│           jquery-3.7.0.slim.min.js
│           scripts.js
├───templates
│       index.html
│       layout.html
│
├───app.py
```

Comment: Tried with flask-2.3.2 and python 3.10.11 and I did not get that error.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, vscode saved my `.html` files using `UTF-8 with BOM` encoding.

Saving with just the `UTF-8` encoding solved the issue.

To save a file with a different encoding using vscode, do the following:

`Ctrl+Shift+P` -> Change File Encoding -> Save with encoding -> UTF-8